# Converting character array with null characters to string

Tags: c++, string

I have a character buffer which I'm using to send messages over a network. I've serialized an integer using memcpy and so there are some null characters in the buffer. Currently, I'm declaring the buffer as a char array and packing the data from the structure m into it using my serialization routine

```
sendline = new char[256];
serialize(m, sendline);

void serialize(myMsg &m, char* out)
{
    uint16_t seq = htons(m.seq);
    memcpy(out, &m.type, sizeof(m.type));
    memcpy(out + sizeof(m.type), &seq, sizeof(seq));
    memcpy(out + sizeof(seq) + sizeof(m.type), m.data.c_str(), m.data.length());
}
```

My question is- can I use a string here instead of a char array? I tried making sendline a string, but it terminates the buffer on the first null character.

Comment: You also have the option of using `std::vector`.

Comment: Hadn't thought of that. Yes, vector works great. Thanks!